# How does Java represent an image using a byte[] array?

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm just curious how java manipulate images and image processing. In matlab, image is saved as a 3D array of RGB values. But in Java we use byte[] arrays to store an image. But that array is a 1D array.

I'm wondering how this array can represent RGB values and position of voxels?

Comment: The array's size is [imagewidth * imageheight] and is iterated accordingly.

Comment: Everything can be stored as a byte array. The encoding/decoding is what matters.

Comment: Curious: What kind of image is a **3D** array of RGB values? I can understand 2D, but 3D with RGB values seem weird. How do you see the pixels inside the cube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not only java. Low level screen memory use byte[] (linux frame buffer for example)

Depending on bpp (bits per pixels) size.
For 32 bpp you have 4 bytes for r,g,b,a values.
A color value goes from 0 to 255.
Each image line following the precedent in a one byte array.
Then width x 3 give you the 3rd row first pixel position.
Total size is width x height x bpp / 8

32bpp is the simplest to understand.

24bpp is 3 bytes for r,g,b
16bpp is 2 bytes for r,g,b then g is between to bytes...

depending on the encoding it can be r,g,b,a or b,g,r,a or a,r,g,b...